# ORA-02291: integrity constraint with all tables having foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, ddl, ora-02291

I am trying to populate my database but get ORA-02291: integrity constraint error no matter what order I try to insert data. Should I populate before making the fk(although this seems backwards for a database)? I get the error for every single insert into statement. Sorry I am new at pl/sql. Here is my code:

```
--
-- department Table
--
CREATE TABLE department (
    name         VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
    major        VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
    minor        VARCHAR2(45),
    chair_id     NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
    chair_email  VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE department ADD CONSTRAINT departrment_pk PRIMARY KEY ( name );


--
-- faculty TABLE
--
CREATE TABLE faculty (
    faculty_id     NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
    cs_id          VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
    faculty_email  VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
    status         VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
    name           VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
    department_name  VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE faculty ADD CONSTRAINT faculty_pk PRIMARY KEY ( faculty_id,
                                                            faculty_email );



--
-- student TABLE
--
CREATE TABLE student (
    student_id     NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
    student_email  VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
    ethnicity      NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
    standing       VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
    name           VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
    gender         VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
    faculty_id     NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
    faculty_email  VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE student ADD CONSTRAINT student_pk PRIMARY KEY ( student_id,
                                                            student_email );



--
-- course TABLE
--
CREATE TABLE course (
    course_number         NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
    hours            NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
    title            VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
    section          NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
    department_name  VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
    faculty_id       NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
    faculty_email    VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE course ADD CONSTRAINT course_pk PRIMARY KEY ( course_number );


--
-- location TABLE
--
CREATE TABLE location (
    building_number         NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
    room_number             NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
    department_name  VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL
);


--
-- student_took_course TABLE
--
CREATE TABLE student_took_course (
    student_id     NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
    student_email  VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
    course_number  NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
    grade          NUMBER(10)
);

--
-- create forgein keys
--
ALTER TABLE course
    ADD CONSTRAINT course_department_fk FOREIGN KEY ( department_name )
        REFERENCES department ( name )
            ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE course
    ADD CONSTRAINT course_faculty_fk FOREIGN KEY ( faculty_id,
                                                   faculty_email )
        REFERENCES faculty ( faculty_id,
                             faculty_email )
            ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE student_took_course
    ADD CONSTRAINT course_number_fk FOREIGN KEY ( course_number )
        REFERENCES course ( course_number )
            ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE department
    ADD CONSTRAINT department_faculty_fk FOREIGN KEY ( chair_id,
                                                       chair_email )
        REFERENCES faculty ( faculty_id,
                             faculty_email );

ALTER TABLE faculty
    ADD CONSTRAINT faculty_department_fk FOREIGN KEY ( department_name )
        REFERENCES department ( name );

ALTER TABLE location
    ADD CONSTRAINT location_department_fk FOREIGN KEY ( department_name )
        REFERENCES department ( name );

ALTER TABLE student
    ADD CONSTRAINT student_faculty_fk FOREIGN KEY ( faculty_id,
                                                    faculty_email )
        REFERENCES faculty ( faculty_id,
                             faculty_email );

ALTER TABLE student_took_course
    ADD CONSTRAINT student_id_fk FOREIGN KEY ( student_id,
                                               student_email )
        REFERENCES student ( student_id,
                             student_email )
            ON DELETE CASCADE;


--
-- insert info
--
INSERT INTO department (name, major, minor, chair_id, chair_email) VALUES
    ('mechanical enginering', 'mechanical major', 'mechanical minor', '1', 'bob@mechanical.edu');
INSERT INTO faculty (faculty_id, cs_id, faculty_email, status, name, department_name) VALUES
    ('1', '1', 'bob@mechanical.edu', 'active', 'bob', 'mechanical enginering');
INSERT INTO student (student_id, student_email, ethnicity, standing, name, gender, faculty_id, faculty_email) VALUES
    ('900123456', 'alice@student.edu', '50', 'good', 'alice', 'f', '1', 'bob@mechanical.edu');
INSERT INTO course (course_number, hours, title, section, department_name, faculty_id, faculty_email) VALUES
    ('543', '3', 'fluids', '01', 'mechanical enginering', '1', 'bob@mechanical.edu');
INSERT INTO location (building_number, room_number, department_name) VALUES
    ('12', '103', 'mechanical engineering');
INSERT INTO student_took_course (student_id, student_email, course_number, grade) VALUES
    ('900123456', 'alice@student.edu', '543', '3');

INSERT INTO department (name, major, minor, chair_id, chair_email) VALUES
    ('computer science', 'computer science major', '4', 'jerry@cs.edu');
INSERT INTO faculty (faculty_id, cs_id, faculty_email, status, name, department_name) VALUES
    ('4', '2', 'jerry@cs.edu', 'active', 'jerry', 'computer science');
INSERT INTO student (student_id, student_email, ethnicity, standing, name, gender, faculty_id, faculty_email) VALUES
    ('900987654', 'noah@student.edu', '23', 'good', 'noah', 'm', '4', 'jerry@cs.edu');
INSERT INTO student (student_id, student_email, ethnicity, standing, name, gender, faculty_id, faculty_email) VALUES
    ('900316487', 'bruce@student.edu', '23', 'probation', 'bruce', 'm', '4', 'jerry@cs.edu');
INSERT INTO course (course_number, hours, title, section, department_name, faculty_id, faculty_email) VALUES
    ('460', '4', 'golang', '01', 'computer science',  '4', 'jerry@cs.edu');
INSERT INTO location (building_number, room_number, department_name) VALUES
    ('43', '209', 'computer science');
INSERT INTO student_took_course VALUES
    ('900987654', 'noah@student.edu', '460', '4');

INSERT INTO department (name, major, minor, chair_id, chair_email) VALUES
    ('nuclear enginering', 'nuclear major', NULL, '3', 'james@nuckear.edu');
INSERT INTO faculty (faculty_id, cs_id, faculty_email, status, name, department_name) VALUES
    ('3', '7', 'james@nuclear.edu', 'active', 'james', 'nuclear enginering');
INSERT INTO student (student_id, student_email, ethnicity, standing, name, gender, faculty_id, faculty_email) VALUES
    ('900876543', 'alex@student.edu', '37', 'probation', 'alex', 'm', '3', 'james@nuclear.edu');
INSERT INTO course (course_number, hours, title, section, department_name, faculty_id, faculty_email) VALUES
    ('845', '2', 'reactors', '01', 'nuclear enginering', '3', 'james@nuclear.edu');
INSERT INTO location (building_number, room_number, department_name) VALUES
    ('65', '132', 'nuclear enginering');
INSERT INTO student_took_course VALUES
    ('900876543', 'alex@student.edu', '845', '2');

INSERT INTO department (name, major, minor, chair_id, chair_email) VALUES
    ('biology', 'biology major', NULL, '8', 'elizabeth@biology.edu');
INSERT INTO faculty (faculty_id, cs_id, faculty_email, status, name, department_name) VALUES
    ('8', '6', 'elizabeth@biology.edu', 'active', 'elizabeth', 'biology');
INSERT INTO faculty (faculty_id, cs_id, faculty_email, status, name, department_name) VALUES
    ('2', '9', 'dave@biology.edu', 'resigned', 'dave', 'biology');
INSERT INTO student (student_id, student_email, ethnicity, standing, name, gender, faculty_id, faculty_email) VALUES
    ('900452367', 'paul@student.edu', '05', 'good', 'paul', 'm', '8', 'elizabeth@biology.edu');
INSERT INTO course (course_number, hours, title, section, department_name, faculty_id, faculty_email) VALUES
    ('324', '3', 'micro biology', '01', 'biology', '8', 'elizabeth@biology.edu');
INSERT INTO course (course_number, hours, title, section, department_name, faculty_id, faculty_email) VALUES
    ('113', '3', 'intro to biology', '01', 'biology', '2', 'dave@biology.edu');
INSERT INTO location (building_number, room_number, department_name) VALUES
    ('04', '213', 'biology');
INSERT INTO student_took_course VALUES
    ('900452367', 'paul@student.edu', '324', '4');
INSERT INTO student_took_course VALUES
    ('900452367', 'paul@student.edu', '113', '2');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` option when creating foreign key contraints such as

```
ALTER TABLE department
    ADD CONSTRAINT department_faculty_fk FOREIGN KEY ( chair_id, chair_email )
        REFERENCES faculty ( faculty_id, faculty_email ) 
  DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;

ALTER TABLE location
    ADD CONSTRAINT location_department_fk FOREIGN KEY ( department_name )
        REFERENCES department ( name )
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

in order not to happen constraint validation during the population of the tables before *commiting* them, and after all of the population process are completed decently, you can enable those constraints by using `ENABLE [VALIDATE]` option such as

```
ALTER TABLE department MODIFY CONSTRAINT department_faculty_fk ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE location MODIFY CONSTRAINT location_department_fk ENABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the model (reverse-engineered from your DDL code), it appears that you could remove some of the foreign key constraints.  Some columns can (probably) be removed, too.

**Original model**

[image]

**Modified model**
(will need some more tweaks!)
[image]

Once the DDL code compiles/executes successfully, start populating the "parent tables" first (ie the tables on the "one side" of relationships).  In this case: DEPARTMENT, then LOCATION and FACULTY, then COURSE and STUDENT, and then STUDENT_TOOK_COURSE.  If you write INSERTs for each table as a block of statements as it were - rather than mixing the inserts for the various tables, as you have done originally - it should be easier to spot mistakes, and should also allow you to run all INSERTs successfully.

Example (using all of the INSERTs of your questions, with a few adjustments): see [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7f0eedd027622c8ec269c4e8f17ac465).